# Filter Data based on values of single column

Tags: oracle, self-join

I have a table with following data. Now I only want to select GRP_ID whose ITEM_NO are only of Parcel Type. In case there are items which have TTYPE both as Parcel and Truck, then that should not come in result.

```
GRP_ID  ITEM_NO TTYPE
00001   12345   Parcel
00001   12346   Parcel
00001   12347   Parcel
00002   12348   Parcel
00002   12349   Parcel
00002   12349   Truck
```

So for above data only `GRP_ID='00001'` should come in result. I tried following but I guess there must be better way:

```
select * from myitem where GRP_ID not in (
    SELECT GRP_ID FROM myitem where TTYPE='Truck'
);
```

Please help me here.

Comment: if it works, take it.

Comment: select * from myitem where grp_id in (select grp_id from myitem where ttype='Parcel' minus select grp_id from myitem where ttype='Truck');

Comment: Hi Roger, Yup it worked as I was expecting, Thanks for this... Do you have any consideration on which query will perform better when loads of data?

Comment: if grp_id and ttype are indexed (ttype first element in index) then this minus operation is completely resolved in the index.  another index on gpr_id by itself means that the outer select is indexed as well.  this should scale well.  In my experience the NOT IN does not scale as well as MINUS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do an explain plan because the transformer probably unnested the subquery. In that case, it won't be as inefficient as it seems and that query will run fine. However, here's a more semantically clean query (may or may not be better than the transformed plan):

```
select GRP_ID
from myitem
group by GRP_ID
having min(TTYPE) = max(TTYPE) and
       min(TTYPE) = 'Parcel';
```

This will make sure that each group has only one type, and that one type is Parcel.

Comment: Good on Jonathan,, Not a very booking construct of query.. and i like these style.. hopefully it is also good when it comes to performance,, Any thoughts on that?

Comment: It should be very efficient, since it's only tracking two aggregate columns.